# Как назвать питомник крокодилов?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте!
Часто в зоопарках вижу табличку "крокодилярий". Имеется в виду крокодилий питомник. А правильное ли это слово? Как-то оно режет слух.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это окказиональное слово, образовано по регулярной словообразовательной модели (ср. *дельфинарий*). Словарями это слово не зафиксировано, однако оно принадлежит русскому языку (построено с использованием русских аффиксов).

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EA%F0%EE%EA%EE%E4%E8%EB%FF%F0%E8%E9

Answer (score 1):

Я согласен с tat (и с gramota.ru), но не вижу никаких причин для "...л**я**рия".
Первое что, пришло мне в голову после прочтения только названия темы - крокодил**а**рий. 
"Солярий" - это цельное заимствование, там мягкое **ЛЬ** оправдано.

А вообще есть полупризнанное международное слово "рептилярий", но там могут обитать не только крокодилы, но самая разная живность - вплоть до черепах и ящериц.